# Non correct values in object transform Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing this short code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class IngredientsController : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{

    public GameObject BunPrefab;
    public Transform canvas;

   public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
   {
        print("Drag started");
   }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print("Dragging...");
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print("End Drag");
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print(eventData);
        print(this.gameObject.transform.position);
        switch (this.gameObject.name)
        {
            case "BunButton":
                GameObject Bun = Instantiate(BunPrefab) as GameObject;
                Bun.transform.SetParent(canvas);
                Bun.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
                Bun.transform.position = eventData.position;
                break;
        }
    }

   /* private void IngredientChecker()
    {

    }*/
}
```

And when I change position of Bun object(Bun.transform.position = eventData.position;) this changes to X: 58000 and to Y: 86000. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: you are probably getting screen values. You need to convert this position to world position using Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint function.

Comment: the values you see in the Inspector are the localPosition relative to the parent object. And it seems that your Canvas has some local Scale different from (1,1,1) -> never do this. Leave the canvas at (1,1,1) and if necessary rather scale children via the RectTransform's sizeDelta, never the scale